# stopping Networkmanager and wpa_supplicant : FAIL on shutdown or on restart

Tags: network-manager, shutdown, systemd, wpa-supplicant

Ubuntu 22.04 Jammy Jellyfish

reboot or shutdown fail because  NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant can't stop.

If I stop NetworkManager and wpa_supplicant by hand before shutdown, shutdown works fine, else shutdown reports

```bash
systemd-shutdown[1]: Waiting for process: wpa_supplicant, NetworkManager
INFO: task NetworkManager:849 blocked for mare than xxx seconds
      Tainted: G          I       5.19.0-32-genereic #33~22.04.1-Ubuntu
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
```

and there is the same message for wpa_supplicant

Do you have any idea of what happens and how I can fix it.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```bash
sudo dpkg-reconfigure network-manager network-manager-gnome network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome network-manager-pptp network-manager-pptp-gnome wpasupplicant
```

works for me. I imagine that some of these package reconfiguration are not essential.

Thanks